# Run a webserver within an android application

Tags: android, webserver, android-webview

I have an android application that uses a webview to display some of its screens.
The problem - it takes a lot of time for the android webview pages to download the images from the remote server. Therefore I thought about starting a webserver within my android application (in a new thread) that will serve the static images.

I was able to start the webserver in a thread on port 8080 (from my application), but wasn't able to access it from my application via webview on url "10.0.2.2:8080", "127.0.0.1:8080" and "localhost:8080".
Any ideas why I wasn't able to access my webserver?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2):

Would you consider directly load HTML data into webview instead?

```
String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. I'm using the webview to open a web application within my android app, and I also have a few more mobile apps that use the same web application with the same pages, so I only want to serve the images/js code that takes the longest to load instead of the entire html page (otherwise code reuse will be difficult)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to run a server for loading static content. Android webview has a method loadDataWithBaseURL for this porpose

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a lot of images, or if the total size isn't too much you can just include your images as assets in your app.

You can load static HTML into a webview that references the images that you deployed with your app.

A quick reference for how to use local images in HTML for a webview is located here: http://www.androidsnippets.com/webview-with-custom-html-and-local-images

Comment: Can I use this to load a remote html page with local images?

Comment: I've never tried anything like that but I would think that it would work - give it a shot and see.